# matching the closest strings to a search term (perl regex)

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Basically, what I'm trying to do is search through a rather large PHP file, and replace any block of PHP code that includes the string "search_term" somewhere in it with some other code. I.e.

```
<?php
//some stuff
?>
<?php
// some more stuff
$str = "search_term";
// yes...
?>
<?php 
// last stuff
?>
```

should become

```
<?php
//some stuff
?>
HELLO
<?php 
// last stuff
?>
```

What I've got so far is

```
$string =~ s/<\?php(.*?)search_term(.*?)\?>/HELLO/ims;
```

This correctly matches the closest closing `?>`, but begins the match at the very first `<?php`, instead of the one closest to the string `search_term`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, I don't like to use non-greedy matching, because it usually leads to problems like this.  Perl looks at your file, finds the first `'<?php'`, then starts looking for the rest of the regexp.  It passes over the first `'?>'` and the second `'<?php'` because they match `.*`, then finds `search_term` and the next `'?>'`, and it's done.

Non-greedy matching means that you have a regular expression that matches more things than you really want, and it leaves it up to perl to decide which match to return.  It's better to use a regular expression that matches exactly what you want to match.  In this case, you can get what you want by using `((?!\?>).)*` instead of `.*?` (`(?!\?>)` is a negative look-ahead assertion)

```
s/<\?php((?!\?>).)*search_term((?!\?>).)*\?>/HELLO/is;
```

If you expect multiple matches, you might want to use `/isg` rather than `/is`.

Alternatively, just split the file into blocks:

```
@blocks = split /(\?>)/, $string;
while (@blocks) {
    $block = shift @blocks;
    $sep = shift @blocks;
    if ($block=~/search_term/) {
        print "HELLO";
    } else {
        print $block, $sep;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The block thing was actually ideal in my particular scenario

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put your first capture group back into your replacement.  Something like this:

```
s/<\?php(.*)<\?php(.*?)search_term(.*?)\?>/<\?php$1HELLO/ims
```

Comment: just tried this... it doesn't get rid of the part before `search_term`

Comment: hooray! got it working with: `s/<\?php(.*)<\?php(.*?)search_term(.*?)\?>/<\?php$1HELLO/ims`

Comment: What if `search_term` is inside the first `<?php ... ?>` block?

Answer (score 2):

```
$string =~ s/<\?php(?:(?!\?>|search_term).)*search_term.*?\?>/HELLO/isg;
```

`(?:(?!\?>|search_term).)*` matches one character at a time, *after* making sure the character isn't the beginning of `?>` or `search_term`.  When that stops matching, if the next thing in the string is `search_term` it consumes that and everything after it until the next `?>`.  Otherwise, that attempt fails and it starts over at the next `<?php`.

The crucial point is that, like @RobertYoung's solution, it's not allowed to match `?>` as it searches for `search_term`.  By not matching `search_term` either, it eliminates backtracking, which makes the search more efficient.  Depending on the size of the source string that may not matter, but it won't noticeably hurt performance either.

@Benj's solution (as currently posted) does not work.  It yields the desired output with the sample string you provided, but that's only by accident.  It only replaces the **last** code block with `search_term` in it, and (as @mob commented) it completely ignores the contents of the very first code block.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/(.*)<\?php.*?search_term.*?\?>/${1}HELLO/ims;
```

In your regular expression, the regex engine is trying to find the earliest occurence of a substring that matches your target expression, and it finds it between the first `<?php` and the second `?>`.

By putting `(.*)` at the start of the regex, you trick the regex engine into going to the end of the string (since `.*` matches the whole string), and then backtracking to spots where it can find the string "`<?php`". That way the resulting match won't include any more `<?php` tokens than necessary.

Comment: **If** you only wanted to replace one code block, this would be a better solution than @Benj's.  But that's not how I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using <s>greedy</s>stingy matching but that can still match too much.

[*Matching repetitions* in `perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions) describes it well.

I sometimes use negated matches to help but I don't think it will help. For example:

```
s/^[^A]*A/A/
```

to make sure my characters aren't matched.

But I'm not usually trying to cross multiple lines and I'm not using perl unless I have to.

Comment: Erm where? `.*?` is non-greedy.

Comment: True. I'm wrong, but there is definately more being matched than is wanted.